# Можно ли представить результат запроса в виде класса?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

К примеру, имеется запрос вида:

```
SELECT
    oc.id,
    caas.hydrant_from,
    caas.hydrant_without,
    pb.concrete_volume,
    pb.diameter_inner,
    pb.diameter_outer,
    pb.height,
    pb.name_product,
    pt.name_type,
    sn.name_schema,
    ht.name_hatch_height,
    ht.name_hatch_type,
    tt.throat_type_height,
    tt.name_throat_type,
    u.*,
    un.name_unit,
    un.hydrant
FROM
    wk_cas_construction_and_assembly_scheme AS caas
    INNER JOIN productbrand_throattype AS temp
    INNER JOIN wk_cas_product_brand AS pb
    INNER JOIN wk_cas_product_type AS pt
    INNER JOIN wk_cas_schema_name AS sn
    INNER JOIN wk_other_hatch_type AS ht
    INNER JOIN wk_other_throat_type AS tt
    INNER JOIN wk_cas_unit AS u
    INNER JOIN wk_cas_unit_name AS un
    INNER JOIN wk_mainwork_object_composition AS oc
    INNER JOIN wk_mainwork_object AS o
WHERE
    o.id = 77 AND
    pb.id = caas.product_brand_id AND
    pb.id = temp.productbrand_id AND
    pb.product_type_id = pt.id AND
    tt.id = temp.throattype_id AND
    tt.id = oc.throat_id AND
    tt.hatch_type_id = ht.id AND
    u.id = oc.unit_id AND
    u.unit_name_id = un.id AND
    u.schema_name_id = sn.id AND
    caas.schema_name_id = sn.id;
```

Возможно я даже смогу написать его на HQL, но вернется мне, как понимаю, `List<Object[]>`.
Может есть возможность представить это в виде класса с полями что указаны в SELECT или как ни будь по другому, но что бы было цивилизованно?
**UPD:**
К ответу. Не знаю, конечно, кому это может пригодиться.

```
public List<SpecificationData> getAllById(Long id) {

    Session session = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    List<SpecificationData> result = new ArrayList<SpecificationData>();

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        connection = session.disconnect();

        String query =
            "SELECT " +
                "oc.id AS objCompID, " +
                ~~~
                "pt.id AS productTypeID, " +
                "ht.id AS hatchTypeID " +
            "FROM " +
                "wk_cas_construction_and_assembly_scheme AS caas " +
                "INNER JOIN productbrand_throattype AS temp " +
                ~~~
                "INNER JOIN wk_mainwork_object AS o " +
            "WHERE " +
                "o.id = ? AND " +//77
                ~~~
                "caas.schema_name_id = sn.id " +
                "ORDER BY objCompID, productTypeID ASC;";

        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setLong(1, id);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            SpecificationData specificationData = new SpecificationData();

            specificationData.setObjCOmpID(rs.getLong("objCompID"));
            ~~~
            specificationData.setHatchTypeID(rs.getLong("hatchTypeID"));

            result.add(specificationData);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {

        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        log.error("Ошибка при выборке по id. id = " + id.toString(), e);

    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите - это [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) (связь объектов в БД с экземплярами классов).
Современные ORM, например Hibernate, позволяют автоматически преобразовывать экземпляры класса (Entity) в сущности таблиц БД. В вашем случае перечень атрибутов состоит из атрибутов нескольких таблиц, поэтому так сделать не получится. Вам придется делать маппинг самостоятельно - [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462099/mapping-resultset-to-pojo-objects).

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!

Comment: Вы это(upd в вопросе) имели в виду?

Comment: Да, что-то примерно такое

Answer (score 3):

HQL поддерживает конструкцию

```
select new SomeClassName(a.fieldOne, a.fieldTwo) from AnotherClassName a
```

В результате которой вам вернётся экземпляр класса SomeClassName, если у вас имеется таковой с подходящим конструктором.